# BottomNavigationView navigation items text displayed above icon

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

After upgrading dependency:

> 'com.google.android.material:material:x.x.x'

from **1.4.0** to **1.5.0**, the navigation items text has somehow changed from being anchored below the icon to on top of it:

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

Is this a feature or a bug and does this have a fix?

Comment: I do not think so . It works fine for me on 1.5.0 and 1.6.0 alpha01

Comment: I had the same issue and reverted back to 1.4.0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was facing the same problem after updating from 1.4.0 to 1.5.0, but in my case the problem was caused because I was using a theme for the BottomNavigationView that inherited from `Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView`:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bnv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
    ...
/>
```

After looking at the `Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView` xml I realised that in version 1.5.0 a `minHeight` attribute has been added, causing the problem affecting us.

So I added `<item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>` to my custom style like this:

```
<style name="Widget.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
    ...
    <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

And the problem was solved!

Answer (score 5):

Reading the [release notes of 1.5.0](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.5.0) I could see the `Material3` theme introduction. I went over the [`BottomNavigation.md`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/4ade45077d8fb92e097eda7656c4c80e3712dda4/docs/components/BottomNavigation.md) and then I figured it out: turns out [it's needed to use the new `Material3`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/4ade45077d8fb92e097eda7656c4c80e3712dda4/docs/components/BottomNavigation.md#implementing-bottom-navigation-theming) theme instead of `MaterialComponent`:

```
<style name="Theme.Inventory" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="bottomNavigationStyle">@style/Widget.App.BottomNavigationView</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.Material3.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.BottomNavigationView</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.BottomNavigationView" parent="">
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/shrine_blue_100</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/shrine_blue_900</item>
</style>
```

Also, I removed the `android:theme="@style/MyBottomNavigationView"` from the `BottomNavigationView` in `xml`.